# SQL very slow when where condition contains IS NULL OR LEN(@localvariable)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, where-clause

I have a query which is much **slower** when I include the following line in the `where` condition:

```
-- @locCandidates IS NULL OR LEN(@locCandidates) = 0
```

I am passing order numbers (optional) and candidate names (optional) as filters.

The candidates can be comma separated for more than 1 name search.

Could anyone point out what could be the reason for slow performance please and how else could I write my final select?

Here is the SQL :

```
DECLARE @Candidates NVARCHAR(MAX)   = 'ann' 
    
DECLARE @locCandidates NVARCHAR(max) = @Candidates     
 create table #Temp
(
    CandidateName Varchar(50)
)

DECLARE @candidateFiltered AS TABLE(Id INT);  
IF @locCandidates IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@locCandidates) > 0  
BEGIN  
    Insert Into #Temp SELECT * FROM   dbo.fn_Split(@locCandidates, ',')
    Insert into @candidateFiltered
    SELECT w.Id    FROM dbo.Workers w, #Temp  WHERE CONCAT(LOWER(w.FirstName), ' ', LOWER(w.LastName)) LIKE CONCAT('%',LOWER(CandidateName),'%');  
    If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') Is Not Null)
    Begin
        Drop Table #Temp
    End
END    
    
SELECT oc.OrderId       
FROM dbo.Orders o 
INNER JOIN dbo.OrderCandidates oc ON oc.OrderId = o.Id    
WHERE oc.WorkerId IN (SELECT [Id] FROM @candidateFiltered) 
OR (@locCandidates IS NULL OR LEN(@locCandidates) = 0 )--Alternative to this??
```

Comment: A scalar comparison like the one you've highlighted is quick.  Are you sure it's not the CTE that the if statement controls?  Consider putting the results from the fn_split into a temp table.
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/04/01/stored-procedure-and-temporary-tables.aspx

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Since `@LocCandidates` is fixed and you are testing it already you can add an `else` and have two versions of your query inside each `if` branch and not need to test `@LocCandidates` inline at all.

Comment: `OR` can often be slow... try `LEN(COALESCE(@locCandidates,'')) = 0`

Comment: Extensively explained in this article: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/revisiting-catch-all-queries

Answer (score 0):

@locCandidates is a text field. Text operations are costly. If the two-dimensional join that you have has lots of records, say, 100 000 000, then whatever the cost to evaluate the LEN operation, for instance is, it is performed 100 000 000 times. Let's assume, that it takes 0.000001 seconds. Then it takes 0.000001 * 100000000 seconds, that is 100 seconds, more than a minute. Instead of that, You could use if-else conditionals, so this recurring evaluation is done exactly once instead of 100 000 000 or so times.

Comment: You can also precompute the condition and add the logical result into the query if that suits you better.

Comment: do you mean this?

Comment: @Anna sorry, I do not understand the question. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IF statement instead of the `OR` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
IF @locCandidates IS NULL OR LEN(@locCandidates) = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT oc.OrderId       
    FROM dbo.Orders o 
    INNER JOIN dbo.OrderCandidates oc ON oc.OrderId = o.Id      
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT oc.OrderId       
    FROM dbo.Orders o 
    INNER JOIN dbo.OrderCandidates oc ON oc.OrderId = o.Id    
    WHERE oc.WorkerId IN (SELECT [Id] FROM @candidateFiltered) 
END
```

Comment: How is this answer different from mine?